# How can we update configMap value by using another configmap in runtime

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

we are trying  configmap keyvalue should be update in another configmap in runtime

we are tried by using the code value is updated but it is not applying in runtime

Comment: can you provide YAML manifests?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.